# Blur & Unblur background on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am after this desired effect [here](http://canva-com-hero-effect.webflow.io/)

I am of the understanding that you place the clear background (fixed) above the blured background and apply a mouseover effect, however knowone has on SO has asked this question before.

Any ideas how to implement the effect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you please share the code you've tried so far?  Is there anything you can glean from examining the code on the site you linked?  Remember, we're willing to help, but we're not a coding service.  :)

Comment: It's a canvas, fairly cpu intensive code that

Answer (score 0):

Oldest JS trick in the book:-)

```
.trail { /* className for the trail elements */
 position: absolute;
 height: 6px; width: 6px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: teal;
}
```

Pay attention to the javascript

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/yJEKYv

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `filter: blur();` for this, instead of ramping up the amount of page requests by duplicating images (blurred, and non-blurred).

So, for example:

```
.blur-unblur-background-on-hover {
  background: #101010 url('https://www.unsplash.it/612') no-repeat;
}

.blur-unblur-background-on-hover:hover {
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

**Resources**

- [Can I Use](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=blur)
- [CSS3 Filter Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)